# Is there an equivalent to C++'s class-scoped enum?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In C++ I might do the following in a header:

```
cClass {
  enum eList { FIRST, SECOND };
}
```

... and this in some other class:

```
cClass::eList ListValue = GetListValue();
if(ListValue == cClass::FIRST) {
  ...
}
```

Is there an equivalent either using straight Objective-C language features or some trickery in Cocoa which would allow similarly **scoped** `enum`s?

Comment: Objective-C has no namespaces and no class constants. You can simulate it only using name prefixes.

Comment: I've never tried this for enum, but keep in mind that you can have an Objective-C++ file suffixed "mm" and have C++ constructs in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can emulate parts of it using C:

create a C enumeration and type:

```
enum MONEnumType : uint8_t {
  MONEnumType_Undefined = 0,
  MONEnumType_Red,
  MONEnumType_Green,
  MONEnumType_Blue
};
```

declare container:

```
struct MONEnum {
  const enum MONEnumType Red, Green, Blue;
};
```

declare storage:

```
extern const struct MONEnum MONEnum;
```

define storage:

```
const struct MONEnum MONEnum = {
  .Red = MONEnumType_Red,
  .Green = MONEnumType_Green,
  .Blue = MONEnumType_Blue
};
```

in use:

```
enum MONEnumType ListValue = GetListValue();
if (ListValue == MONEnum.Red) {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Spot on. It's a pretty bloaty way to have to do it, but it's a workaround for if I need it. For now I'll stick to prefixed enum values though. Cheers :)

Comment: @sjwarner right -- it does not meet all points that C++ offers here. even though it is basically code duplication, it can save clients a lot of code (if C++ is not an option). you're welcome.